# Why console application fails to retrieve mocked service during testing?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.7

I have the following console application:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Services\Myservice;

class MyCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'test';
    
    public function handle(Myservice $service){
       dump($service->dummy());
    }
}
```

And I have the following service:

```
namespace App\Services;

class Myservice
{
   public function dummy()
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

I also made the following test:

```
namespace Tests\Console;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;

use Mockery;

class TestMyCommand extends TestCase
{

   public function testCommand()
   {
       $service = Mockery::mock(Myservice::class);
       $service->shouldReceive('dummy')->andReturn(true);

       app()->bind(MyService::class,$service);

       $this->artisan('test')
       $service->shouldHaveReceived('dummy')->andReturn(true);
   }

}
```

But I retrieve the following error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Console\TestMyCommand::testCommand
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method dummy(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0__Tests_Console_MyService should be called
 at least 1 times but called 0 times.

/var/www/html/api/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/CountValidator/AtLeast.php:47
/var/www/html/api/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Expectation.php:312
/var/www/html/api/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/ReceivedMethodCalls.php:46
/var/www/html/api/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/VerificationDirector.php:36
/var/www/html/api/tests/Console/MyCommand.php:20
```

So why I am unable to provide a mocked service to the command?

#Edit 1:

I tried the following:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Console;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
use Tests\CreatesApplication;
use Mockery;

class TestMyCommand extends TestCase
{
   use CreatesApplication;

   public function testCommand()
   {
       $service = Mockery::mock(Myservice::class);
       $service->shouldReceive('dummy')->andReturn(true);

       app()->instance(MyService::class,$service);

       $this->artisan('test');
       $service->shouldHaveReceived('dummy')->andReturn(true);
   }

}
```

And the following:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Console;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
use Tests\CreatesApplication;
use Mockery;

class TestMyCommand extends TestCase
{
   use CreatesApplication;

   public function testCommand()
   {
       $service = Mockery::mock(Myservice::class);
       $service->shouldReceive('dummy')->andReturn(true);

       $this->app->instance(MyService::class,$service);

       $this->artisan('test');
       $service->shouldHaveReceived('dummy')->andReturn(true);
   }

}
```

But still get the error:

```
Time: 3.32 seconds, Memory: 38.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Console\TestMyCommand::testCommand
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method dummy(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0__Tests_Console_Myservice should be called
 at least 1 times but called 0 times.

/var/www/html/api/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/CountValidator/AtLeast.php:47
/var/www/html/api/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Expectation.php:312
/var/www/html/api/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/ReceivedMethodCalls.php:46
/var/www/html/api/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/VerificationDirector.php:36
/var/www/html/api/tests/Console/TestMyCommand.php:21

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Errors: 1.

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
```

Comment: Could you try: `$this->app->instance(MyService::class, $service);` instead of `app()->bind(MyService::class,$service);`

Comment: and there are two mistakes in your code: `$soapService` should be `$service` and it should just be `$service->shouldHaveReceived('dummy');`, you cannot call `andReturn()` here.

Comment: @Remul I tried it and still get the error.

Comment: Hmm, I just copied your command, test and service and it works for me on Laravel 8.21.0

Comment: I guess laravel 5.7 has the issue then.